# Why can't iterate through this list in a Django template

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a variable from my view that is the output of a Model.objects.all() call on that Model. I'm passing it to my template in my view, and I'm trying to iterate over it in the template. I can access the first element of it simply by this line of code. 'code' is the name of a field in my django model. This line does print the first element's 'code' attribute correctly.

```
{{ var_name.0.code }}
```

However, when I try to iterate over var_name in a template for loop, nothing shows up. I tried the following code:

```
{% for single_var in var_name %}
    {{ single_var.code }}
{% endfor %}
```

This isn't actually what I want to do in the for loop, but getting this to work will let me do what I need in the template. It may be noteworthy to add that at the moment this list has only one element in it.

This is for a work project, so that's why I changed the variable names to something generic.

Comment: Can you show how you're defining the list and passing it to the template?

Comment: Does print 'var_name' print the list of objects? Similarly, does printing just 'single_var' on each iteration print the object reference?

Comment: The var_name is declared from calling ModelName.objects.all(). Printing out var_name shows [<ModelName: 'description of model'.>]. I printed var_name in the view and the template, and I get the same thing printed out in the browser and in the output of runserver in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that changing the name of single_var to something without an underscore seemed to fix it. This doesn't make a lot of sense to me because the [Django template language documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) states the following:

```
Variable names consist of any combination of alphanumeric characters and the underscore ("_").
```

Does anyone know why this seemed to fix the problem?